# Multitouch Issue with Google Map in JS

Tags: google-maps-api-3

In the multitouch browser (tried IE10, IE11 on touch machine and using Visual Studio simulator in touch pinch mode) map object fires click event for pinch zoom gesture (it is not fired for swipe however ):

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function (arg) {
    console && console.log ("click");
});
```

**Question:**
is there a way to have Google map not to fire click on pinch gesture?

Thanks